# How to release an allocated bar button item

Tags: objective-c, ios, uibarbuttonitem

Can I autorelease the following?

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton] autorelease];
```

it works and removes an Analyzer warning I was getting. if not, how would I go about releasing it correctly.

thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct.

The leftBarButtonItem is a property that retains the UIBarButtonItem, so yes it is a good approach.

Without the autorelease message it will cause a memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

That's the right way (although the right way now is to use ARC).

An accepted alternative (in non-ARC environment) is:

```
UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButton;
[barButton release];
```

The setter of navigationItem retains the button itself so the object returned by alloc/init has to be released in order to balance the retain counts in one of the
described ways (alloc/init returns object with retaincount 1 and the setter adds +1 to that).

This is definitely **NOT** recommended:

```
[self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem release];
```

Answer (score 1):

it is correct, also you can do this

```
UIBarButtonItem *item = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = item;
[item release];
```